# Testing REST service with soapUI (trial version)

Tags: rest, testing, soapui

I would like to use soapUI (trial) to POST to a REST service. I setup the request. When I post a one line JSON it works fine. If I POST a JSON text with line breaks (PrettyPrint) I get the HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

I already tried changing the following properties

- Strip whitespace
- Remove empty content
- Entitize properties

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a **server** error, what is your server saying internally (logs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. Be sure to include quotes in your JSON document. soapUI works fine